# 'jupyter notebook' command opens some files in Pycharm instead of browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried casually launching Jupyter notebook via Windows Powershell with `jupyter notebook` command, but instead notebook it launched PyCharm with two files:

jupyter.py containing:

```
"""Launch the root jupyter command

Alias to jupyter_core
"""

__version__ = '1.0.0'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from runpy import run_module
    run_module('jupyter_core')
```

And empty file named notebook.txt

I use Python 3.10.11 without Anaconda (also use pip and sometimes venv. idk if it relevant, this error occurs without virtual enviroments)

What did I did wrong?

Trised running file in PyCharm, but got:

```
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: 1.0.0 console dejavu events execute kernel kernelspec
lab labextension labhub migrate nbconvert notebook qtconsole run server
troubleshoot trust

Please specify a subcommand or one of the optional arguments.

Process finished with exit code 1
```